# Scheduled task error instantiating agent

Tags: scheduled-tasks

Has anyone seen this one before?  It's complaining about no matching constructor, but the implementation class has no other constructor other than the default.

This is Sitecore 9.1.1 btw.

```
2456 03:00:22 WARN  Could not find constructor in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Availity9.ScheduledTasks.CacheWarmer. The constructor parameters may not match or it may be an abstract class. Parameter info: Count: 2. Parameter types: System.String, System.String

2456 03:00:22 ERROR Error while instantiating agent. Definition: web/sitecore/system/tasks/schedulestrue

Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException

Message: Could not create instance of type: Availity9.ScheduledTasks.CacheWarmer. No matching constructor was found.

Source: Sitecore.Kernel

   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)

   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)

   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)

   at Sitecore.Tasks.Scheduler.ReadAgents()
```

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: I don't anyone saw this cause it's in a custom class `Availity9.ScheduledTasks.CacheWarmer`. Check the code of that class and maybe add it to your question (with the task definition). Otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I meant if anyone has seen that error in general.  So I put in it a constructor taking two string params.  And now get different error "Message: Could not find property 'LogActivity' on object of type: Availity9.ScheduledTasks.CacheWarmer".  Seems like it's expecting my class to inherit from something.  Is that maybe something new and different in 9x?

Comment: Can you add the configuration of your agent and its code? Are you sure you want to register agent? Maybe you should work with scheduled job instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I learned that in the config entry,  tags become parameters that your method signature must have. Other tags within the entry must be properties in your implementation class.

It's a whole other story if you define the tasks in CMS system->Tasks (Commands and Schedules).

In my case I didn't need any of the parameters or properties that were in the examples I'd found online.

And naturally I was defining the tasks both in CMS and config, and was getting errors from both.

Then I happened upon an article that boils it down to the simplest way of implementing a task and defining it in a config patch at Jon D Jones site:

https://www.jondjones.com/learn-sitecore-cms/sitecore-developers-guide/sitecore-events/how-to-set-up-a-scheduled-task-in-sitecore

Once I deleted the CMS commands and schedules and implemented the simple way, all works fine.  The only caveat would be the xdt:Transform="Insert" property in his  tag. That gave me an error and I just removed it and all was fine.